# Can't find element that should exist?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding tabs to my tab control through code:

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();

var stack = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = header });
stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Name = "extra" });
tab.Header = stack;

tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
```

As you can see, it creates the header of the tabItem with a stack panel. It adds two text blocks; one of which is empty, but I've assigned the name "extra". What I would like to do is, later in the code, edit the textBlock named "extra" and add some new text to it.

How would I find and edit this element? I have tried the following code, but its producing an error saying the element can not be found:

```
object test = Application.Current.FindResource("extra");
```

Comment: At first, `tabControl` is probably not a [Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources(v=vs.110).aspx), but a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Why not access it through a `get`?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindName` is what you are looking for but your TextBlock is not in the correct WPF Namescope.

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you add an object to an object tree at a point in time after the XAML that produced that tree was parsed, a Name or x:Name value on the new object does not automatically update the information in a XAML namescope. To add a name for an object into a WPF XAML namescope after XAML is loaded, must call the appropriate implementation of RegisterName on the object that defines the XAML namescope.

For example:

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock() { Name = "extra" };
stack.Children.Add(textBlock );
RegisterName(textBlock);

...

TextBlock textBlock = FindName("extra") as TextBlock;
```

Finally, `Application.Current.FindResource("extra")` is returning null because the element does not exist when project resources are created. [More on FindResource.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [FrameworkElement.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var control = tab.FindName("extra");
if(control is TextBlock){
    // your logic here
}
```

You don't need `Application.Current.Resource` dictionary here because it's different collection. If you want to use it then you should put user controls within Resource dictionary beforehand.

Comment: You're assuming I have access to "tab". The code is being executed in a user control. The tabItem is being constructed in the MainWindow. I have access to the tabControl, but not the tabItem itself.

Comment: Actually main window also has FindName on it, and "extra" name should be unique to the window. Try mainWindow.FindName("extra") instead of tab.FindName("extra")

Answer (score -1):

Because you are trying to find resource with the key "extra". It's wrong.

Try this:

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();

var stack = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
var textBlock = new TextBlock() { Name = "extra" }
stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = header });
stack.Children.Add(textBlock);
tab.Header = stack;

tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
```

Now you can reach it with textBlock instance.

Comment: Not the same. There is no need to access XAML from codebehind, because you are adding elements in codebehind. You've already got instances and can use them. Just assigned them to a variable.

Answer (score -2):

Here's some VB WPF code for what you need

```
    Dim test As TextBlock
    test = DirectCast(FindName("extra"), TextBlock)
```

I have no idea if it will work like that in C# WPF although if that doesn't work try looking up CType